# What to do when nodes in a Cassandra cluster reach their limit?

Tags: database, cassandra

I am studying up Cassandra and in the process of setting up a cluster for a project that I'm working on. Consider this example :
Say I setup a 5 node cluster with 200 gb space for each. That equals up to 1000 gb ( round about 1 TB) of space overall. Assuming that my partitions are equally split across the cluster, I can easily add nodes and achieve linear scalability. However, what if these 5 nodes start approaching the SSD limit of 200 gb? In that case, I can add 5 more nodes and now the partitions would be split across 10 nodes. But the older nodes would still be writing data, as they are part of the cluster. Is there a way to make these 5 older nodes 'read-only'?  I want to shoot off random read-queries across the entire cluster, but don't want to write to the older nodes anymore( as they are capped by a 200 gb limit).

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I can say that 99% of the queries will be write queries, with 1% or less for reads. The app has to persist click events in Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when cluster reach its limit we add new node to cluster. After adding a new node, old `cassandra` cluster nodes will distribute their data to the new node. And after that we use `nodetool cleanup` in every node to cleanup the data that distributed to the new node. The entire scenario happens in a single DC.

> For example:
>
> Suppose, you have 3 node `(A,B,C)` in `DC1`  and 1 node `(D)` in `DC2`. Your nodes are reaching their limit. So, decided to add a new node `(E)` to DC1. Node `A`, `B`, `C` will distribute their data to node `E` and we'll use `nodetool cleanup` in `A`,`B`,`C` to cleanup the space.

Comment: Holy **** . That's awesome. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Problem in understanding the question properly.

I am assuming you know that by adding new 5 nodes, some of the data load would be transferred to new nodes as some token ranges will be assigned to them.

Now, as you know this, if you are concerned that old 5 nodes would not be able to write due to their limit reached, its not going to happen as new nodes have shared the data load and hence these have free space now for further write.

Isolating the read and write to nodes is totally a different problem. But if you want to isolate read to these 5 nodes only and write to new 5 nodes, then the best way to do this is to add new 5 nodes in another datacenter under the same cluster and then use different consistency levels for read and write to satisfy your need to make old datacenter read only.

But the new datacenter will not lighten the data load from first. It will even take the same load to itself. (So you would need more than 5 nodes to accomplish both problems simultaneously. Few nodes to lighten the weight and others to isolate the read-write by creating new datacenter with them. Also the new datacenter should have more then 5 nodes). Best practice is to monitor data load and fixing it before such problem happen, by adding new nodes or increasing data limit.

Considering done that, you will also need to ensure that the nodes you provided for read and write should be from different datacenters.

Consider you have following situation :

> dc1(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
>
> dc2(n6, n7, n8, n9, n10)

Now, for read you provided with node n1 and for write you provided with node n6

Now the read/write isolation can be done by choosing the right Consistency Levels from bellow options :

> *LOCAL_QUORUM*
>
> or
>
> *LOCAL_ONE*

These basically would confine the search for the replicas to local datacenter only.

Look at these references for more :
[Adding a datacenter to a cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html)
and
[Consistency Levels](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding was this: If I add a node to a cluster, the data in the older nodes would remain where it is , but with cassandra's vnodes and a decent partitioning strategy, new data would now be emitted to the new node and the older node would keep getting data as well. Are you saying that by adding a node, Cassandra would take some data from the older nodes, transfer it to the new one, and then delete this transferred data from the older node?

Comment: I am saying almost same.If you are adding node to same datacenter then some of the token ranges would be assigned to it to contribute to the overall data load(which would be informed to the other nodes through gossiping). The data corresponding to this token ranges would be hold by that new node. Hence some old node would be releasing some of their own load.

Comment: Also, this new distribution of data would not be uniform. But by running *nodetool repair* this could be balanced. PS. Its *nodetool cleanup*